# Continuous inverse of an unbounded operator on a Hilbert space

Tags: operator-theory, inverse-function, unbounded-operators

Let $T:D(T)\to H$ be an unbounded densely defined operator on a Hilbert space $H$. Suppose that $T^{-1}$ is continuous, i.e. that $0$ belongs to the resolvent set $\rho(T)$ of $T$.

As $T^{-1}$ exists, this means that $T$ is injective, isn't it? So $T^{-1}$ is a left inverse (but not necessarily a right one, correct?).

Alternatively, suppose that I have the following informations:

By definition, $T^{-1}f = u\iff f = Tu$. If for any $f\in H$, there exists a unique $u\in D(T)$ such that the previous holds, this exactly means that the operator $T^{-1}$ is continuous, no? Actually, this overall means that $T$ is surjective, which seems to imply that $T$ is bijective since being invertible means that it is injective.

My main questions:

1. Is the reasoning about the continuity of $T$ right?
2. Where is the flaw in my reasoning about the injectivity and surjectivity. This would mean that any operator with $0$ in its resolvent set is bijective from $D(T)$ to $T$ which seems to be surprising for some operators such as the laplacian on an appropriate domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Your reasoning about continuity is wrong. Best is to read a bit about continuity.

2) Yes, the map is a bijection

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For 1) I got it. In my particular case, it is continuous for other reasons and my initial question was idiot. 2) I am not completely sure of that. I mean, it would imply that any injective unbounded operator is bijective. Actually, I think that $T^{-1}f=u\iff f=Tu$ is false. We only have, $Tu=f\implies T^{-1}f=u$ as $T^{-1}$ is a left inverse. On the other hand, if for any $f$, there exists $u$ such that $Tu=f$, then it is surjective, which is not always the case, is it?

Comment: Ok, so to restate the claim : any injective unbounded operator with continuous inverse is a bijective map between its domain $D(T)\subset H$ and $H$. Is that right?

Comment: Ok, you answered to my question with the assumption that for any $f$, there is a $u$, etc. So it is a bijection!